# Everything is ok but someKindOf Error showing on logcat while playing video

Tags: java, android, textureview

I'm playing video on Textureview. Everything seems to be ok.

It is showing this error contiuously.

```
04-09 12:49:17.722 155-15138/? E/VSP: VSP_RELEASE_Dev, 256, ret: 0
04-09 12:49:17.742 155-15138/? E/VSP: VSP_ACQUIRE_Dev, 198
```

What this means? What can I do to eliminate this?

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: Those lines in the description (3,4) are showing on the error tab of LC with red color continuously. This can be error but what it is exactly is the question.

Comment: is your app's name VSP?

Comment: No. But It only appears when playing Video.

Comment: Then ignore it. It may be an internal error of device manufacturer implementation or Android SDK. edit-> VSP tag is related to android media codec. Please search it and ignore.

Comment: maybe it can be from this app. Maybe someone knows about it.